# CHtml::link() not creating link

Tags: php, yii

I have a CHtml that is printing on the html as text instead of as a link. How do I get it to create the link?

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$albumModel,
    'attributes'=>array(
        // "album_Id",
        array(
            'label'=>'Album',
            // 'value'=>CHtml::link(Chtml::encode($albumModel->album_Id))
            'value'=>CHtml::link(Chtml::encode($albumModel->album_Id),
                                array('album/view','id'=>$albumModel->album_Id)),
        ),
        'title',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Results:

Album   a href="/trackstar/yii/framework/trackstar/index.php/album/3"3/a

Title   I Won't Give Up - Single

(insert<> where they're suppose to be, needed to remove to show actual results)

Comment: I wasn't missing the designated type property. 'type'=>'html'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `type` to `raw`. The type `html` will purify (see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtmlPurifier) the value and then just return it. Type `raw` means it will output the value just as you insert it. In this case as the link.

```
...
'label' => ...,
'value' => ...,
'type' => 'raw',
...
```